# How can I change the server name indication in a Python request?

Tags: python, python-requests, sni

I have been looking around the Internet, and have only been able to find solutions to set the SNI in other languages, but was not able to find a solution for Python.

I want to be able to change the SNI for a standard Python request like this, but I am not sure if it is achievable

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
response = session.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

For example, the SNI for this request would show that the host is "www.google.com", however I would like to find a way to change that.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to do [domain fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting) using `requests`, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jobec/0a797ca165c725417ab1229fc33d8265) may be what you are after.

Comment: Not sure if domain fronting is what I'm looking for, just need to change the TLS SNI

Comment: What do you mean by "disable host-name checking"? The very nature that you need SSL cert check means a hostname check must be done for the certificate, and then the `Hostname:` field of the underlying HTTP request (if present) will then serve the site, i.e. another layer.  You have not indicated whether or not you are doing domain fronting, nor have you indicated whether or not that gist serves what you are after.  In any case, if you are trying to apply this technique on Google's server, [they do not support domain fronting](https://www.theregister.com/2018/04/19/google_domain_fronting/).

Comment: To be clear, in that gist, `fronted_domain="fronted.digi.ninja"` argument is the TLS hostname to use for SNI, and `headers={"Host": "d1sdh26o090vk5.cloudfront.net"}` explicitly sets the hostname for the underlying HTTP server to dereference to the actual server you wish to connect to.  This technique you are describing is called "domain fronting".